# Cannot insert to table with authenticated role policy in Supabase

Tags: supabase

I'm trying to insert a row in my table which has RLS enabled and the `Enable insert for authenticated users only` policy added.
Unfortunately, I cannot insert even though I'm correctly login.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create submissions table

```
create table submission (
  stuff text
);
```

2. Enable RLS

```
alter table submissions
  enable row level security
```

3. Add Policy

```
CREATE POLICY "Enable insert for authenticated users only" ON public.submissions FOR INSERT WITH CHECK (auth.role() = 'authenticated');
```

4. On client, I log in using magic links (the object is correctly added in localstorage so I know I'm log in)
5. I try to insert

```
const { data, error } = await supabase
 .from("submissions")
 .insert({ stuff: 'hello' });
```

**The `Authorization Bearer <Jwt>` is present in http call.**

6. But I got error

```
{
  "hint":null,
  "message":"new row violates row-level security policy for table \"submissions\"",
  "code":"42501",
  "details":null
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found what was wrong.

The thing is, the default behaviour of `supabase.insert` returns the row we just inserted, in other words it selects it (reads it) from the table. As I didn't added a Policy to read the table, it failed.

So two solutions:

1. Add a new Policy to be able to SELECT from that table
2. Add `{ returning: "minimal" }` to the `supabase.insert` so it does not send the row back

Answer (score 1):

Yep -- I ran into the same thing the first time I tried to add a RLS policy that only allowed INSERT and not SELECT (for letting users log info to a table.)

We've discussed making `{ returning: "minimal" }` the default for insert, update, and delete, but I don't think that will happen.

It's just something to be aware of (and it is in the documentation, but easy to miss.)

Comment: Thanks @Mark! Maybe if you could check other issue of mine as well, that would be fantastic: https://github.com/supabase/supabase/discussions/3524
:)

Comment: Done!  And I'm happy to help.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks @Mark, that will be helpful.
If you'll have some spare time, I would be happy to jump on a quick call (google meet or something, it should last 20min or so :)) with you to talk about the (definitly improvable) design structure I've set up for my voting system.
If you do have some spare time, let me know and I'll send you an email :) Many thanks!

Comment: The best thing to do is to join our Discord channel and hit me up (or one of the other developers).  You can reach me there as @burggraf.